# VScode autocomplete weird behaviour Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, visual-studio-code, autocomplete

I know there are several topics dealing about VScode autocomplete issues, but none of those solutions worked for me.

In my situation, the variable type seems to be recognized by VScode:

[image]

But when trying to get methods from Line2D, they are not shown:

[image]

I do not have this behaviour for local modules in my current wdir.
I have Python IntelliSense and Pylance extensions installed, and this is my settings.json:

```
{
    "python.pythonPath": "/usr/bin/python3",
    "python.linting.pylintEnabled": true,
    "python.linting.enabled": true,
    "python.autoComplete.extraPaths": [
        "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/matplotlib/"
  ],
  "python.analysis.extraPaths": [
    "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/matplotlib/"
  ]  
}
```

I added matplotlib path into the 'extraPath', but I believe it is already located in a default path for python libs.

I am on Jetson Xavier Ubuntu 18.04, VScode 1.60.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reinstall **Python** extension and set `"python.languageServer": "Pylance"`, then reload window.

If not work, after resetting VS Code by deleting data folders `$HOME/.config/Code` and `~/.vscode`, reinstall **Python** extension:

[image]

**[UPDATE]**

I test on my machine and it indeed has no autocomplete and intellisense about Lin2D, but you can still use its methods and run python file successfully.
[image]

I've put a [github issue](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/17394) and hope get help there, please follow it.

Comment: Hi @Molly Wang-MSFT , well I can get the same result as yours when resetting VScode, but in your example you missed the comma "," after the variable line ( at line 2), so you get a tuple from plt.plot.

But what I would like to have is to get all the properties and method from the Line2D class: https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.lines.Line2D.html

Am I missing something?
Thanks!

Comment: @DiXcipuli. Sorry for the misunderstanding about your question, I've update my answer please have a look at it.